# Need all MySQL's log files from Amazon RDS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I need Amazon RDS MySQL's log files of last five days. In Amazon RDS, it is showing recent five log files only.

**Can anyone help me to get MySQL's log files of last five days from Amazon RDS?**

Thank you all.

Answer (score 0):

The answer will vary depending on which logs you are talking about (bin logs? error logs? general log?) and your parameters and backup settings.

I'd recommend contacting Amazon RDS team via their [support page](http://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport) or their [developer forum](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/forum.jspa?forumID=60):

Thanks.